# Selenium C# - how to use element by "nobr"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this hml code:

```html
<nobr class="ms-crm-Form-Title-Data autoellipsis">
  Text - Some Text
```

I would like to get the text value by selenium driver. how can I do that? I have tried with CssSelector:

```js
 [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "nobr[class = ms-crm-Form-Title-Data autoellipsis]")]
 public IWebElement ApplicationNumberLabel { get; set; }
```

but I'm getting Could not find element Error.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about using `By.tagName` something like : `driver.findElement(By.tagName("nobr")).getText())`. This is in Java though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find an Element with selenium in C# you do it like this:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TheId"));
```

In this case By.Id is the selector this can be XPath, Css, Tag, Id and many other selectors. If you want to select based on multiple css classes you need XPath.

```
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///C:/Users/notmyname/Desktop/test.html");
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//nobr[@class='ms-crm-Form-Title-Data autoellipsis']"));
        textBox1.Text = element.Text;
    }
```

Comment: @YanivEliav No problem, go [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) and select C# as preference at the top of the page. This page will help you with all the basics.